# Azure QnA shows URL on facebook chat

Tags: azure, facebook, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

After making sure the training of the QnA chatbot is done, I tested it on the QnA website and this is how it looks there:
[image: QnA test chatbot]

However, when I create the chatbot app on facebook and tested it this is how it looks like:
[image: facebook chatbot]

Is there a way to embed the link in the word the same way as it was embedded in the QnA without making the url appear. It's the same thing for inserting an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QnAMaker makes use of markdowns to store answer text. **The rendering links will depend on what formats are supported for the channel.** Different channels support different rendering formats and a specific format might work in a particular channel and might not in another.

Example:

[image]

Similarly, for rendering images, you can add images to a QnAMaker answer by adding the URl via markdowns.

[image]

> The knowledge base supports Markdown. However, the auto-extraction from URLs has limited HTML-to-Markdown conversion capability. If you want to use full-fledged Markdown, you can modify your content directly in the table, or upload a knowledge base with the rich content. Multimedia, such as images and videos, is not supported at this time.

Also, **QnA Maker doesn't process the image in any way. It is the client application's role to render the image.**